# How to get the Oldvalue of a Combobox's (2) column?

Tags: vba, ms-access

I am trying to code something that stores the changes(the old and new value) that been made to the form am working on. My code is working fine but my problem is with the combo-boxes and their bounding.
For instance, I have Gender combo-box, its source table like this:-

```
 ID    CODE    GENDER
 1     0       Male
 2     1       Female
```

and it is bounded to column(1). 
When there is a change lets say from Male to Female the gender.OldValue will be 0 ,but what i really want is that OldValue  could catch the corresponding value on Column(2) which is the text "Male" not 0

the code below is what i tried with no luck.

```
Dim ctl As Access.Control
Dim old_val As String
Dim new_val As String
Dim fld_name As String
For Each ctl In Me.Controls
    If ctl <> ctl.OldValue Then
       fld_name = ctl.Name
       old_val = ctl.OldValue.Column(2) 'or ctl.Column(2).OldValue and both gives an error
       new_val = ctl.Column(2)
    End If
next ctl
```

Any help would be appreciated,thanks in advance.

Comment: combobox Properties `OnEnter` event you will get the old value and by `on Change` event you will get new value. have you tried this events?

Comment: You would have to run this in either the forms before Update event or the individual controls before Update event for you to do anything with it. That's when the Old Value property is set. Not sure what the final objective is though?
Also not every control would have a .OldValue so the code would fall over at that point.

Comment: @Minty am already running it from "before update" event and my final objective is to Insert the old value and new value along with the field name into a new table to keep trak of changes.and it is working perfectly ,my only problem is with the bound problem i explained earlier .

Comment: Okay Audit trial. Have a read of this thread to see if it helps steer you in the right direction https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29617067/audit-trail-in-access-2010-database

Comment: @Minty Thanks i checked it out but it didn't address my problem ,as i mentioned before, my code is working and am not looking for an alternative.I guess am not clear enough explaining my problem.Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can reference anything other than the bound column using .Oldvalue .
Combo.column(2).OldValue is never stored as such, so you can only reference it "live" as it were.

As it's related data you could always simply look it up I guess.

Comment: am starting to think so.

Answer (score 0):

The way I would do it is to use an unbound combo box and use VBA to change the actual field value either through DAO or SQL or even on a hidden bound control.

Comment: thank you but that is a lot of work for what i thought it old be a simple task.

Answer (score 0):

1. Write the new value in memory.
2. Set the control back to `.OldValue`.
3. Capture `Column(x)` for history or whatever.
4. Write the new value back.

```vb
strNew = Nz(ctlX.Column(1), "*emty*")
varMemoryValueNew = ctlX.Value 
ctlX.Value = ctlX.OldValue
strOld = Nz(ctlX.Column(1), "*emty*") 
ctlX.Value = varMerkerValueNew
```

Answer (score 0):

also in Access 2019 the value of another than the boundcolumn like .oldvalue.Column(2) or .column(2).oldvalue does not work.
So the solution @mohamed shubber is the most easiest, to pick the oldvalue of the bound column and do a Dlookup in order to get the value you are looking for. I use this, fast and easy.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

For anyone who is facing the same dilemma,the only workaround i could think of is to take the OldValue and run a Dlookup function on it against its source table.